# Why does my transaction on Ethereum come after another transaction with less gas?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain

Both my opponent and I executed transactions to the same smart contract at the same time. However, my transaction was executed later, even though my gas was higher. It's really strange.
[My tx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3OkC.png)
[Opponent's tx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhALi.png)

I was use web3js library for smartcontract calling

Answer (score 0):

Transaction order in a block is decided by the block producer.

They usually have an incentive to order the transactions from the highest gas price to the lowest (earns them more fees) - but they can decide to use different order if they wish.

For example to prefer their own transactions or to extract MEV (if you're interested in this topic, read up on *flashbots*).